# How to assign a function to a checkbox or value instead of button (drawing)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Since buttons only work on PC I am trying to make this sheet work properly on android. I'll be attaching this time keeping sheet link below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v8y91EIVoSWexMIMjghB2wEbO3pvUltjUSbTtogvbIU/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the script as well:

```
function clockIn() {

//DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//DEFINE MAIN SHEET
var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");

//LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();

for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
{
// CHECK CLOCK IN
if(mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue() ==  mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
{
Browser.msgBox('Need to Clock Out before Clocking IN');
return;
}

}

// ADD CLOCK IN RECORD
mainSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue(mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue()).setFontSize(12);
mainSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);

}


function clockOut() {

//DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//DEFINE MAIN SHEET
var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");

//LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();

var foundRecord = false;

for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
{
// FIND CLOCK IN RECORD
if(mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue() ==  mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
{
// UPDATE CLOCK IN RECORD
mainSheet.getRange(j,3).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);
var totalTime = (mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() - mainSheet.getRange(j,2).getValue()) /(60*60*1000);
mainSheet.getRange(j,4).setValue(totalTime.toFixed(2)).setNumberFormat("#0.00").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);
foundRecord = true;
}

}

// IF NO CLOCK IN RECORD
if(foundRecord == false)
{
Browser.msgBox('Need to Clock In First');
return;
}

// CALL TOTAL HOURS
TotalHours();

}

function TotalHours()
{

//DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//DEFINE MAIN SHEET
var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");

//LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();

//DEFINE ARRAY
var totals = [];

//LOOP THROUGH ALL RATES
for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
{
var rate = mainSheet.getRange(j, 4).getValue();
var name = mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue();
var foundRecord = false;

for(var i = 0; i < totals.length; i++)
{
//FOUND RECORD ADD TO TOTAL
if(name == totals[i][0] && rate != '')
{
totals[i][1] =  totals[i][1] + rate;
foundRecord = true;
}
}

//ADD NEW RECORD, EXISTING RECORD NOT FOUND
if(foundRecord == false && rate != '')
{
totals.push([name, rate]);
}

}

//CLEAR DATA
mainSheet.getRange("F5:G1000").clear();

//DISPLAY TOTALS
for(var i = 0; i < totals.length; i++)
{
mainSheet.getRange(5+i,6).setValue(totals[i][0]).setFontSize(12);
mainSheet.getRange(5+i,7).setValue(totals[i][1]).setFontSize(12);
}
}
```

Comment: I think the only way that you can get that to work is by using onEdit() and capturing the correct  cell for the checkbox via `e.range.rowStart` and `e.range.columnStart` or `e.range.getA1Notation();`

Comment: I don't following links to spreadsheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to run the functions of `clockIn()` and `clockOut()` by checking the checkboxes instead of the buttons.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification point:

- In this case, in order to run the script by checking the checkbox, it uses the OnEdit trigger. From your current script, I thought that the simple trigger of OnEdit can be used.

When this point is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

At first, please insert 2 checkboxes to the cells "F1" and "F2. In this sample script, when the checkbox of "F1" is checked, the function `clockIn()` is run. When the checkbox of "F2" is checked, the function `clockOut()` is run. And, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. In order to run the script, please check the checkbox.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const checkboxes = {"F1": clockIn, "F2": clockOut};
  const a1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "MAIN" || !checkboxes[a1Notation] || !range.isChecked()) return;
  checkboxes[a1Notation]();
  range.uncheck();
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to use the methods which are required to authorize, please use the installable OnEdit trigger instead of the simple trigger. Please be careful this.
- If in your situation, when several users are used the checkboxes, I would like to recommend to use the lockService.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='your sheet name' && e.range.getA1Notation()=='check box location ' {
    run function 
  }
}
```